# Change date and time to UTC format

Tags: java

I have input date and time "2021-05-03T15:46:09.354+08:00"

I want UTC format output - "2021-05-03T07:46:09.354Z"

Any Idea and suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Input string fits an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) and output string fits an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), so:

```java
Instant instant = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-05-03T15:46:09.354+08:00").toInstant();
System.out.println(instant); // prints: 2021-05-03T07:46:09.354Z
```

You can also use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and the result can be also be `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

```java
ZonedDateTime inZoned = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-05-03T15:46:09.354+08:00");
ZonedDateTime outZoned = inZoned.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(inZoned + " -> " + outZoned);
// prints: 2021-05-03T15:46:09.354+08:00 -> 2021-05-03T07:46:09.354Z

OffsetDateTime inOffset = inZoned.toOffsetDateTime();
OffsetDateTime outOffset = inOffset.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(inOffset + " -> " + outOffset);
// prints: 2021-05-03T15:46:09.354+08:00 -> 2021-05-03T07:46:09.354Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont have enough reputation to comment, but have you tried using the Instant class in Java? Link to javadoc. The parse() might be able to help, then you can call toString() on the Instant.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
                            .ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSXXXXX");
     
    //Date string with offset information
    String dateString = "03-08-2019T16:20:17:717+05:30";
    System.out.println("input date: "+dateString);

    //Instance with given offset
    OffsetDateTime odtInstanceAtOffset = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

    //Instance in UTC
    OffsetDateTime odtInstanceAtUTC = odtInstanceAtOffset.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
     
    //Formatting to string
    String dateStringInUTC = odtInstanceAtUTC.format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

    //Convert OffsetDateTime to instant which is in UTC
    System.out.println("expected date :"+odtInstanceAtOffset.toInstant());
}
```

ouput:
input date: 03-08-2019T16:20:17:717+05:30
expected date :2019-08-03T10:50:17.717Z